# changing getElementById to getElementsByClassName breaks code

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementsbyclassname

So I've got this working code

```
<details>Hello World<summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another<summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>

<button id="expand" onclick="openAll()">Expand All +</button>

var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");

function openAll() {
  for (var i = 4; i <= 31; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
  }
  document.getElementById("expand").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: closeAll();" );
  document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML = "Collapse All -";
}

function closeAll() {
  for (var i = 4; i <= 31; i++){
    elems[i].removeAttribute("open");
  }
  document.getElementById("expand").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: openAll();" );
  document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML = "Expand All +";
}
```

Now I've decided I want to add a second button so I changed the `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName` so I have

```
<details>Hello World<summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another<summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<button class="expand" onclick="openAll()">Expand All +</button>
<button class="expand" onclick="openAll()">another Expand All +</button>

var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");

function openAll() {
  for (var i = 4; i <= 31; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName("expand").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: closeAll();" );
  document.getElementsByClassName("expand").innerHTML = "Collapse All -";
}

function closeAll() {
  for (var i = 4; i <= 31; i++){
    elems[i].removeAttribute("open");
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName("expand").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: openAll();" );
  document.getElementsByClassName("expand").innerHTML = "Expand All +";
}
```

On the first click the code expands all but does not change the text nor does it collapse. What am I missing?

Comment: what is details in `document.getElementsByTagName("details");`

Comment: It's the `<details>` tag in html5

Comment: There is no such element by tag 'details' in your html.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop iterating through 31-4=27 times, even though you are having only two `details` tag. `getElementsByClassName` returns collection. If you want work with the items from the collection you have to use index.
Try the following code:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");

function openAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
  }
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("expand");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("expand")[i].setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: closeAll();" );
    document.getElementsByClassName("expand")[i].innerHTML = "Collapse All -";
  }
}

function closeAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i <elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].removeAttribute("open");
  }
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("expand");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("expand")[i].setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: openAll();" );
    document.getElementsByClassName("expand")[i].innerHTML = "Expand All +";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="expand" onclick="openAll()">Expand All +</button>
<button class="expand" onclick="openAll()">another Expand All +</button>

<details>Hello World<summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another<summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns a collection of elements, so you need a loop in order to interact with each individual element.

```
var exp = document.getElementsByClassName("expand");
for (var i = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
  exp[i].setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: closeAll();" );
  exp[i].innerHTML = "Collapse All -";
}
```

And do the same for the other function too.

Also, I think it is better to not set the attribute for onclick, but instead to assign the function directly to the property.

So in the loop, change that one line.

```
  exp[i].onclick = closeAll; // No parentheses!
```

Comment: Tried replacing the two document.getElementsByClassName lines with the above ... same result. Trying to assign the function directly to the property is a no go either.

Comment: Be sure to check for errors in the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

another issue is your for loop, you iterate with: `for (var i = 4; i <= 31; i++){`
But you want to iterate over the number of elements: `var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++`
http://jsbin.com/wisepiduwu/edit?html,js,console,output

**Prior Answer -> partly misunderstood the issue:**
With getElementById you get a reference to an HtmlElement -> ID has to be unique so you get one element.

> The id attribute specifies its element's **unique** identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

getElementById
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID; the ID is a string which can be used to identify the element; it can be established using the id attribute in HTML, or from script.

getElement**s**ByClassName
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names. When called on the document object, the
>   complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also
>   call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only
>   elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the
>   given class names.

Due to you have 2 elements with class "expand" you have to use a for to iterate over this array.

Cheerio :)